# Changing array values while iterating though the same array causes strange behaviour

Tags: c, arrays

I wrote a loop to replace every character in a string with another using a reference array.

```
for(int i=0 ; i < encoded_message_len ; i++){

    for(int j=0; j < 26 ; j++){

        if(encoded_message_copy[i] == substitution_alphabet[j]){

            printf("%c ->>>> %c @ index:%d \n",encoded_message_copy[i], original_alphabet[j], i);
            encoded_message_copy[i] = original_alphabet[j];
        }
    }
}
```

When I run this code however, I get a strange output:

```
J ->>>> C @ index:0
H ->>>> R @ index:1
Q ->>>> Y @ index:2
Y ->>>> Z @ index:2
S ->>>> P @ index:3
U ->>>> T @ index:4
T ->>>> V @ index:4
X ->>>> O @ index:6
F ->>>> L @ index:7
L ->>>> X @ index:7
X ->>>> O @ index:8
B ->>>> G @ index:9
G ->>>> W @ index:9
Q ->>>> Y @ index:10
Y ->>>> Z @ index:10
```

When I remove this line : `encoded_message_copy[i] = original_alphabet[j];` from the loop, I get the expected output:

```
J ->>>> C @ index:0
H ->>>> R @ index:1
Q ->>>> Y @ index:2
S ->>>> P @ index:3
U ->>>> T @ index:4
X ->>>> O @ index:6
F ->>>> L @ index:7
X ->>>> O @ index:8
B ->>>> G @ index:9
Q ->>>> Y @ index:10
```

Can someone explain why this is happening?

Comment: a lot of context is missing here.

Comment: You do not break out of the inner loop when you find the substitution character.  As a result, it is sometimes the case that the updated character is *also* found in `substitution_alphabet`, and substituted again.  Put a `break` statement at the end of the body of your `if` statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put a `break;` after the line you needed to remove to make it correct (inside the for loops)

You change the contents of `encoded_message_copy`, this can cause the statement `if(encoded_message_copy[i] == substitution_alphabet[j])` to match multiple times for the same value of `i` ;-)

Answer (score 1):

You're finding several symbols at the same position.
You need to skip further looking at i-th symbol when you found it.
Try to add `break`:

```
if(encoded_message_copy[i] == substitution_alphabet[j]) {
    printf("%c ->>>> %c @ index:%d \n",encoded_message_copy[i], original_alphabet[j], i);
    encoded_message_copy[i] = original_alphabet[j];
    break;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You're changing your data - an early iteration of the outer loop changes your data so it gets seen later.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that when you use statement

```
        encoded_message_copy[i] = original_alphabet[j];
```

you do not break the loop.

```
for(int j=0; j < 26 ; j++){

    if(encoded_message_copy[i] == substitution_alphabet[j]){

        printf("%c ->>>> %c @ index:%d \n",encoded_message_copy[i], original_alphabet[j], i);
        encoded_message_copy[i] = original_alphabet[j];
    }
}
```

So the loop continues to compare the new substituted character with other characters in substitution_alphabet.

You should break the loop if the character was already substituted

```
for(int j=0; j < 26 ; j++){

    if(encoded_message_copy[i] == substitution_alphabet[j]){

        printf("%c ->>>> %c @ index:%d \n",encoded_message_copy[i], original_alphabet[j], i);
        encoded_message_copy[i] = original_alphabet[j];
        break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
/* msg_ptr is the position within the encoded message */
/* letter is a numeric value which corresponds to letter of the
   alphabet (0 maps to 'A', 1 => 'B', etc. */
for (int msg_ptr = 0 ; msg_ptr < message_len ; msg_ptr++) {
    for (int letter = 0; letter < 26 ; letter++) {
        if(encoded_message[msg_ptr] == substitution[letter]) {
           encoded_message[msg_ptr] = original[letter];
        }
    }
}
```

The problem may become clearer to you now. The problem is that while you modify `encoded_message[msg_ptr]` with the value from the `original[letter]`, the inner loop (the *letter* `for` loop) is next to execute / increment. This means the `if` comparison is done again for an unchanged `msg_ptr` (i) and an incremented `letter` (j) values. This means the comparison is done with the freshly decoded value at `encoded_message[msg_ptr]`.

Once you successfully find and replace the encoded message at a given position, you want to advance to the next character in the `encoded_message` array (i.e. increment the value of `msg_ptr` (i). This can be done using the **`break`** [keyword](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wt88dxx6.aspx).

[Another site](http://www.programiz.com/c-programming/c-break-continue-statement) has some program execution diagrams for the `break` (and `continue`) statement, which may make it clearer.

---

If you have problems understanding why this is necessary (or in other words how nested loops operate), mentally run through the following example in your head, as well as your compiler to see.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
        printf("i=%d j=%d\n", i, j);
    }
}
```

The inner loop (`j`) by default will finish before the next *iteration* of the outer loop (`i`) occurs.